# Remove all Recycle Bin Items from database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, database, recycle-bin

In the recycle bin there are 176100 items. I have tried to remove them using PowerShell but it is unable to remove all. After sometime it stops and gives an error. Tried following PowerShell.

```
$WebApp=get-spwebapplication "http://xxxx:31150/"

foreach ($SPSite in $webApp.Sites)
{
#get the collection of webs
foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
{
write-host "deleting recycle bin for:"
write-host $SPWeb.title ":" $SPWeb.URL "`n"
#Empty the 1st Stage Recycle bin items PERMENANTLY
$SPWeb.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();

#Send the 1st Stage Recycle bin items to 2nd Stage
$SPWeb.RecycleBin.MoveAllToSecondStage();

}
#Empty SharePoint site collection recycle bin (Second Stage Recycle bin) or Admin Recycle bin
$SPSite.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();

write-host "Administrator Recycle bin Items Deleted for:" $SPSite.RootWeb.title "`n"
}
```

In the database there is a table called `dbo.RecycleBin`. So my question: Is there any risk if I delete all rows from this table?

Comment: Two points! (1) You never dispose the web-, or site objects which can cause PowerShell to malfunction if you have many sites. (2) Never ever change anything in a SharePoint database. You will void warranty from Microsoft, and can't get support.

Comment: there is only one top level site. in first round loop is done. any i will try disposing objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't touch the database, but instead of deleting items from 2nd stage Recycle Bin using PowerShell, try disabling it from Central Admin first before running the PS script:

```
Central Administration > Application Management > Web Application General Settings > Set Recycle Bin > Second stage Recycle Bin > OFF
```

Or using PS:

```
$WebApp.RecycleBinEnabled = $false; 
$WebApp.Update(); 
$WebApp.RecycleBinEnabled = $true; 
$WebApp.Update();
```

This should empty the recycle bin, but for more gradual deletion, you could try it like this (notice the Disposes):

```
$WebApp=get-spwebapplication "http://xxxx:31150/"

foreach ($SPSite in $webApp.Sites)
{
    #get the collection of webs
    foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
    {
     write-host "deleting recycle bin for:"
     write-host $SPWeb.title ":" $SPWeb.URL "`n"
     #Empty the 1st Stage Recycle bin items PERMENANTLY
     $SPWeb.RecycleBin.DeleteAll();    
     #Don't think you need to call MoveAllToSecondStage() here anymore as you've just deleted all items permanently, but I could be wrong.
     $SPWeb.Dispose();
    }   

    $SPSite.Dispose(); 
}
```

Comment: Is there any PS command for **Second stage Recycle Bin > OFF**

Comment: `$WebApp.RecycleBinEnabled = $FALSE`;
`$WebApp.Update();`
$WebApp.RecycleBinEnabled = $TRUE;`
`$WebApp.Update();`

Comment: Above commands also remove all recycle bin items.